# How can i merge back two dataframes after applying standardscaler to just one of them?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i am having issues with merging my two dfs. i have a dataframe with 5 columns, 4 are binary one is continous.  I would therefore like to only apply standardscaler to one:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
numeric_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train['temperature']),columns=['temperature'])
X_train_new = X_train.drop(columns=['temperature'])

result =pd.concat([numeric_df,X_train_new],axis=1)
```

however the result is not appending properly it has more rows than numeric_df and x-train-new ? how is this possible when each of these dataframes is of equal length.

How can i be sure that when i concat them as well they are based on original index when numeric_df has an index which is reset after applying standard scaler

```
pd.concat([X_train_new.reset_index(),numeric_df],axis=1)
```

when i do the above howeer it works? what i don't get is why i need to do this, and if after resetting index for both dataframes it corresponds to original

Answer (score 1):

This because you have different indexes in the two dataframes. Try:

```
# this has range index
numeric_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train['temperature']),columns=['temperature'])

# so we make this with range index as well
X_train_new = X_train.drop(columns=['temperature']).reset_index(drop=True)

result =pd.concat([numeric_df,X_train_new],axis=1)
```

Or if you wish to retain the index from `X_train`:

```
numeric_df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train['temperature']),
                          columns=['temperature'],
                          index=X_train.index)    # here

X_train_new = X_train.drop(columns=['temperature'])

result =pd.concat([numeric_df,X_train_new],axis=1)
```